# How can I refactor code to avoid assigning output of a partial ViewHelper to a variable of another partial ViewHelper?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, refactoring

I have some code where I am struggling to separate "data" from "sending data to Zend `partial` View Helpers".  For example, i.e. I want to create "just data", return just data from my data function to a parent caller

```
//contains no $this->partial(), deals only with accumulating data
//that may or may not be used for partial later on
$data = $this->getDataOnly(); 

//deals only with sending data to partial for rendering purposes
$this->generatePartials($data);
```

In the code below I seem to mix both together.  Specifically, I have a `partial` *as part* of my data, and that is what I seek to avoid.

```
// $modalData is an array accumulating data for Zend Partial View Helper
// it already has some data, i.e. id, boolean vars 
foreach($modalData as $i => $value)
{
    // here we are adding 'modalHtml' view helper variable 
    // which will contain HTML gotten from (another) partial
    // Problem:  I am not comfortable using a 'partial' as part of a parent 'partial'
    // (which is further down in the code)

    // what could've been "clean data only" generation is about to be
    // polluted by stuffing a partial into it, mixing data and view
    $modalData[$i]['modalHtml'] = $this->partial(
        "partial/product.phtml", 
        parent::getModalContentData($i)
    );
}

//here we are appending HTML produced from partialLoop, using $modalData
$modalBoxesHtml .= $this->partialLoop("partial/modal_box.phtml", $modalData);
```

**Question:**

can I avoid the part where I am "stuffing a partial (which is HTML code and not data) directly into a variable of another view helper partial"?
Can I use some sort of a better more intelligent construct, similar to `addChild` of a `ViewModel`?

I want to get away from assigning "HTML Blocks" to a view helper variable and only assign actual data.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I might have been able to do what I seek

I moved my `partial` method call into the `partial/*.phtml` file itself

```
<div>
    <?php
    echo $this->partial("partial/product.phtml", $this->modalData);
    ?>            
</div>
```

I now have nested partials.

My data became nested too

```
foreach($modalData as $i => $value)
    $modalData[$i]['modalHtml'] = parent::getModalContentData($i);
```